# Apache redirect regexp: match something that is not following something

Tags: regex, apache, pcre

What regexp should stand for "everything that does not follow 'index.php' should point to 'index.php/$1'" ?

For example, "http://mysite/moo" should point to "http://index.php/moo" while "http://index.php/moo" should not.

I am currently using PCRE regexp (Apache docs are saying that PCRE should be used here) taking no effect: `RedirectMatch (?<=index\.php)(\/.+) /index.php/$1`.

What is the right one?

**UPD:** the point is to use mod_alias only, **ommitting mod_rewrite**

Comment: The negation for the `?<=` that you have is `?<!`

Comment: @mario, `RedirectMatch (?<=index\.php)(\/.+) /index.php/$2` gives eternal redirect to `/index.php/`. Could you advice sometthing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`RedirectCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with a non-matching pattern ("!" prefix). Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^/?index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i do not need mod_rewrite =)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
^/?(?!index\.php)(.+)
```

i.e. a negative lookahead

Comment: seems that it matches URL's, but what should be the redirect rule??? `/index.php/$1` gives recursively endless URL =)

Answer (score 0):

I only tried with a simple redirect to a static site (works):

```
RedirectMatch   ^(?!/index\.htm$).*$    /index.htm
```

Based on this, the following might help you (not tried myself):

```
RedirectMatch   ^(?!/index\.php$)(.*)$    /index.php$1
```

[See also: Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)